# How to resolve this query from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

This code allows inserting in twin tables but with different names and at the same time listed, but I would like to know how to transfer this part of the code with Entity Framework using a model of the database:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    string commandText = $"INSERT INTO {MyTable}{i} (ID, Name, Address) VALUES (10, 'Jesse', '123 La Plaza');";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) { }
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no efficient or direct translation of that SQL into EF.  Attempting to convert it would increase the complexity of the code exponentially more than any perceived benefits.  (i.e. its just not worth it).

That said, if you want to attempt it, start by creating a model for each table.  Then add each table/model as a `DbSet` to your `DbContext`.  Then you will need to construct your `DbSet.Add` statements.  If you use some kind of object mutation library, like Automapper, you might be able to construct this using a loop.  Otherwise each statement will need to be atomic in the code.